# Flutter go_router with bloc authentication redirection not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-go-router

I have an application where the user needs to authenticate in order to have access. I am using the bloc library for state managing the state. My `AuthenticationBloc` holds a status streamed through the `authentication repository`. So if any event happens that changes the status the `Bloc` is aware of it. I took the [example code](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial) as reference.

Now i want to use `go_router` for navigating. This is my SplashScreen Route:

```
GoRoute(
          path: KiGoRouter.splash,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
              listener: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
                if (state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated) {
                  GoRouter.of(context).go(KiGoRouter.home);
                } else if (state.status == AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated) {
                  GoRouter.of(context).go(KiGoRouter.login);
                }
              },
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

When the app starts and the user is unactuhenticated it redirects as it should and displays the login page. Now when the user enters the credentials and the `AuthenticationBloc` status changes to authenticated nothing happens. It stays on the login screen.

I even tested to write the code inside the redirect of `GoRouter` but its the same behaviour. It seems like inside of `GoRouter` the `Bloc` is not updated.

I habe used `get_it` to inject the `AuthenticationBloc` as a `singlton` and provided it before the construction of the MaterialApp.

Even when using context.push(x) to prevent the Listener from being removed from the widget tree, the behavior stays the same.

Has anyone a solution or hint on this?

**UPDATE**

This is my injection of the `AuthenticationBloc` using get_it:

```
locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationBloc(
      authenticationRepository: locator<AuthenticationRepository>(),
      userRepository: locator<UserRepository>(),
      getUserDataUseCase: locator()));
```

And before the build of the `MaterialApp`, I am providing the singleton as a value:

```
BlocProvider.value(value: di.locator<AuthenticationBloc>()..add(AppStartup()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the way to go. The error appeared on another side.